# Windows 8 refresh - where is the baselining tool?

Tags: windows-8-preview

In the BUILD keynote, Steve Sinofsky [talked about](http://www.cnetwork.in/2011/09/Windows-8-reset-and-refresh-make.HTML) the refresh and reset capabilities in Windows 8.

He noted that if you do a refresh, your data and your Metro style apps remain untouched, *but you lose any classic desktop apps you've installed*. However he also said there would be a tool to 're-baseline' your PC so that the refresh would return it to that point - and presumably that would include any classic desktop apps installed at the time of baseline.

So, my question is: **has anyone found this baselining utility yet?** I suspect it may be rolled into dism.exe but I have yet to find the magic formula.

This question is *not* answered in the BUILD conference video: *[Understanding Push Button Reset](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/HW-882P)*. I have googled and binged fairly exhaustively ... so far, no specific answers to be found.

Comment: re-tagged this as windows-8-preview since i suspect in the actual OS, if the baseliner is released, it should not require digging.

Comment: I suspect it isn't there as I have not seen this since installing Win8. But then again, I haven't been looking hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[recimg -CreateImage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/f330558b-56f3-4b53-9d2e-6e0fd024449d)

Comment: Thank you. But it fails for me. I guess this really is a pre-beta.